# Конвертер картинок

Tags: android, java

Дайте, пожалуйста, сайт или программу для конвертации оригинальной картинки в mdpi hdpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Generic icons -> Color = 0%